# How to import an existing library into Go 1.11 as a module?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, module

I am trying out Go 1.11 beta2 with this modules support https://tip.golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Modules__module_versions__and_more.

I have created `go.mod` file looking like this:

```
module example.com/m

require github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws v1.15.0
require github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session v1.15.0
require github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3 v1.15.0
```

But this shows me an error when trying to build:

> go: github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws@v1.15.0: unknown revision aws/v1.15.0
>   go: github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3@v1.15.0: unknown revision service/s3/v1.15.0
>   go: github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session@v1.15.0: unknown revision aws/session/v1.15.0
>   go: error loading module requirements

So, I have a question, should I wait for the moment vendor adds support of modules versions into the library before I can import it using go modules or is there some other syntax I can use right now?

Answer (score 1):

Your module's go.mod should require entire modules.

Try replacing:

```
require github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws v1.15.0
```

With:

```
require github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go v1.15.0
```

You can see the AWS SDK module is defined as `github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go` here:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/master/go.mod

See also this example of a real repository depending on multiple modules from other repositories:

https://github.com/google/go-cloud/blob/master/go.mod